# Regex NodeJS Javascript not applying

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have the following node.js code:

```js
let regex = /^<@&\!?(\d+)>$/g;
console.log("Before match ", gettingargR) // gettingargR = <@&702877893436375100> or <@&!702877893436375100>
gettingargR = gettingargR.match(regex);
console.log("After match ", gettingargR)
console.log("After match value", gettingargR[0])
```

My target (expected) return is `After match  [ '702877893436375100' ]` and `After match value 702877893436375100` 
When I try to achieve this, `console` returns:

```
Before match  <@&702877893436375100>
After match  [ '<@&702877893436375100>' ]
After match value <@&702877893436375100>
```

Which means my regex isn't applying. How can I apply it to my string?

Comment: what do you mean by applying? what's the expected result?

Comment: Edited my question so you can understand better my expected result. @CristianTraìna

Comment: Remove the `g` flag. You've anchored it to the front and back, so it's superfluous and will let you access the matched group as `match[1]`.

Comment: The exclamation mark is not a special character in `regex`. It does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `g` flag from your regexp. The global flag turns off the capture group because it needs to return multiple values therefore the interpretation of the return array changes from a specification of the match to a list of complete matches.

```
let regex = /^<@&\!?(\d+)>$/; // remove the g flag
console.log("Before match ", gettingargR);
gettingargR = gettingargR.match(regex);
console.log("After match ", gettingargR)
console.log("After match value", gettingargR[1]); // capture group is element 1
```

Without the `g` flag the interpretation of the result is different. The return array now has the following structure:

```
[
  '<@&702877893436375100>', // full match
  '702877893436375100',     // first capture group
  // second capture group (if any),
  // third capture group (if any),
  // etc..
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For matching all in the big file you can use exec function. For simple first match use reg without "g" flag:

**Sample:**

```js
const matchAll = (str, reg) => {
  let m;
  let result = [];
  do {
    m = reg.exec(str);
    if (m) {
      result.push(m[1]);
    }
  } while (m);
  return result;
};
gettingargR = `<@&702877893436375100>
<@&!702877893436375100>`;

let regex = /^<@&\!?(\d+)>$/gm;
console.log("After match ", matchAll(gettingargR, regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help.

```
const regex = /^<@&\!?(\d+)>$/g;
const str = `<@&702877893436375100>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

**Verified from https://regex101.com/**